# Do I need to have a running ipfs node to be able to store and retrieve files?

Tags: ipfs

I have a basic flask application that stores and retrieves images. I want to store those images on ipfs by simply posting a request to the application which is probably going to be hosted on Heroku. So, I wouldn't have a running ipfs node. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an IPFS [Gateway](https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/blob/master/docs/gateway.md) to access files without running your own node.

When you pin an IPFS file to your own node and shut it down, your files will not be accessible anymore by yourself or others unless another node pins them as well and stays online.

You can pay IPFS file hosters to pin your file on their nodes, [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/distributed-web-gateway/) and [Eternum](https://www.eternum.io/) are two of them.

Here is a list of more: https://www.reddit.com/r/ipfs/comments/9pb5pf/are_there_any_ipfs_file_hosting_services/

Answer (score 0):

There's [pinata](https://pinata.cloud) as a pin service - with a free tier to get started. :)

Files can be accessed via a public gateway, like ipfs.io or the Cloudflare one.